# Multiple view points

Tags: single-word-requests

What is it called when something can be seen in different ways, whether it be taken wrongly or rightfully how it was meant. Like when someone gives you a look that's questionable.

Comment: Thank you for asking. Some information before we start will help us to give you the correct answer.
Please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.
Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Answer (score 1):

[Ambiguous](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ambiguous) would fit.

> open to or having several possible meanings or interpretations;
>   equivocal: an ambiguous answer.